# The beginning the boy is stuck in a pit with other children he has white hair

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read this manga a long time ago. The main character had white hair. Just a kid who went through rebirth. He was stuck in a deep pit with a girl he liked and some other kids. He had to eat leaves to survive which he shared with the girl. Later the boys were hungry so they were drinking all the girls blood but the main character killed them and fed the girl. He liked his blood. When he fainted he was saved by a guy with a large pig, I think, which later could fly. The boy later tamed a dragon and the girl a large butterfly. They also were about to go to a dragon school